# Angular ag grid valueGetter

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

i am trying to make ag grid table. Basically i have about 8 columns. 3 of them are user inputs and the rest are just mathematical calculations based on some equations.

i figured valueGetter will be a good place to put them (calculations), but for one cell i need to get data from different row and trouble starts there.

this is my column definition, and valueGetter for field `x` is working fine because it's using data from the same row, but, for field `xixi` i have to get data from the previous row. i have tried with gridApi but ofc its undefined.  pls help

```
  columnDefs: ColDef[]=[
    {field: 'r', width:150, cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor'},
    {field: 'y', width:150, cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor'},
    {field: 'x', width:150, valueGetter: function (params) {
      return params.data.r * params.data.y;
    }},
    {field: 'xixi', width:150, valueGetter: function (params){
      if(params.node.rowIndex == 0) {return 0;}
      let indexBefore = params.node.rowIndex
      if(this.gridApi == undefined){return;}
      let dataBefore = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(indexBefore-1);
      let data = params.data.x - dataBefore.x;
      return data;}},
    {field: 'koef', width:150, cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor'},
    {field: 'proizvod', width:150},
    {field: 'deltaY', width:190},
    {field: 'delta4y', width:150},
    {field: 'proizvodSum', width:150},
  ]
```

Comment: sorry, how to ag grid read previous row data. I try to check data `params..node.rowIndex` that value `0` and `1`, then  `this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex` not found that value `getDisplayedRowAtIndex` in ag grid

Comment: yes, gridApi is undefined because it is initialized in onGridReady but calumnDefs is being called before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions to your problem, easiest solution would be to use the grid API that is available in the `params` parameter within your `valueGetter`.

Use the following code for your 'xixi' columnDef:

```
{
      field: 'xixi',
      width: 150,
      valueGetter: function (params) {
        if (params.node.rowIndex == 0) {
          return 0;
        }
        let indexBefore = params.node.rowIndex;
        if (params.api == undefined) {
          console.log('her');
          return;
        }
        let dataBefore = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(indexBefore - 1);
        let data = params.data.x - dataBefore.data.x;
        return data;
      },
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-fo1gkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: i am getting Uncaught Error: AG Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into a timeout, e.g. instead of api.refreshView(), call setTimeout(function() { api.refreshView(); }, 0). To see what part of your code that caused the refresh check this stacktrace.

Comment: are you getting the error in the demo? If not, you've made a mistake in your code somwhere.